# Where can I find pearls in Witcher 3?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I am playing Witcher 3 from after patch 1.05.
Is it possible to buy shells (pearls) from a merchant, or do I have to find them somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For another quest you have to travel to Skellige and meet an older man who wants a black pearl as a gift for his beloved woman.

Geralt has to dive for this rare black pearl. You have to collect many shells from the seafloor until you get one with a black (instead of white) pearl inside. The Skellige coast is one spot where you can collect them.

Otherwise you can buy pearls from merchants (but not for the above quest. I had both - a black and a white pearl in my inventory).

Answer (score 2):

Lamias and sirens usually wear some sea shells as jewelry. You should travel to Skellige and look after points of interest near the coasts !